# How do I format specific columns (e.g., as a percentage or to a number of dp) in a MultiIndex column pandas data frame (in Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, formatting

I am trying to format columns in a MultiIndex data frame in Jupyter Notebook.  In the photo, I want to format all the Z-score columns to 1 d.p. and all the Pctile columns as percentages to 1 d.p. [Columns I'm trying to format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIRsP.png).I am guessing the code I am trying to use does not work because because the data frame is a MultiIndex, and my code does not therefore refer to any specific columns.

I have been trying to use the code as below:

```py
df.style.format({'Z-score': '{:.1f}','Pctile (%)': '{:.1%}'})
```

to format the columns in the attached image. This does not format the columns as I hoped, and instead returns the formatting to default settings (i.e., overrides the display settings I set elsewhere in my notebook).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.